# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views error in asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using `View.OnClickListener`. Code is as given below:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.appCompatButtonLogin:
                AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                runner.execute();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLinkRegister:
                // Navigate to RegisterActivity
                Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentRegister);
                break;
        }
    }
```

My `AsyncTask` class is like this:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait!");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                verifyFromSQLite();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void verifyFromSQLite() {
            if (inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }
            if (inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }
            if (inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }

            if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
                    , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {


                Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersListActivity.class);
                accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                emptyInputEditText();
                startActivity(accountsIntent);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private void emptyInputEditText() {
            textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
            textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run my code, I get an `exception` like this:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

I'm trying to separate UI from non-UI part in asynctask, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you google for this error message? There are a ton of answers in Stack Overflow alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make changes to UI in a background task.
Move this code:

```
Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersListActivity.class);
accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
emptyInputEditText();
startActivity(accountsIntent);
```

and

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to `onPostExecute()`.  
You can set values to `boolean` flags for these cases in `doInBackground()` and check them in `onPostExecute()` and act accordingly.